# Prove that the closure of the set $T(A)$ is a compact subset of $C[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $T:C[a,b] \to C[a,b] $ be defined by $$(T(f)(x)):=\int_{a}^x f(t) dt $$ and let $A$ be a bounded subset of $C[a,b]$. Prove that the closure of the set $T(A)$ is a compact subset of $C[a,b]$

MY Idea: 
Arzela-Ascoli Theorem: 
I want to show the closure of $T(A)$ is closed ( which is obvious ), uniformly bounded and equicontinuous.

Uniformly boundedness of $T(A)$:

Let for any $f\in A $ then  $ ||f||_{\infty} <\infty$ because $A$ is bounded subset of $C[a,b]$

$ sup ||Tf||_{\infty}< \infty$ can be shown easily.

But I have problem to show equicontinuity of $T(A)$.
How I tried is like below:

for any $f ,g \in A$ we can write: $$||Tf-Tg||_{\infty} = \underset{x \in [a,b]}{sup} |T(f)(x)-T(g)(x)| \leq \underset{x\in [a,b]}{sup}\int_{a}^x |f(t)-g(t)|dt$$

How do I go from here if I am on the right way?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Saying that $T(A)$ is equicontinuous means that for all $\varepsilon>0$ you can find $\delta>0$ such as
\begin{equation*}
|x-y|<\delta, g\in T(A) \implies g(x) - g(y) < \varepsilon .
\end{equation*}
For $g\in T(A)$, there is an $f$ such as $g=T(f)$, and for that $f$ we have $g(x)-g(y)=\displaystyle\int_{x}^{y}f(t)dt$.

How can you use the boundedness of $A$ now ?

Comment: Sure ,we can use the boundedness of A on $f$.

Comment: Yep, it gives $T(f)(x)-T(f)(y) \leqslant M|x-y|$ so that you get a bound that does not depend on $f$: that is equicontinuity !

Comment: I am kind of confused , because the domain of $T(A)$ is $C[a,b]$. Do not we have to take the element from $C[a,b]$ instead of $[a,b]$

Comment: Okay.Showing $T(A)$ is equicontinuous , how does this proves the closure is also equicontinuous?

Comment: Well if $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ and $f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(y) < \varepsilon$ for all $n$, then we also have $f(x)-f(y) < \varepsilon$. Arzela-Ascoli's theorem can be reformulated like this: the relatively compact sets of $C([a,b])$ are exactly the bounded equicontinuous sets. A set is relatively compact iff its closure is compact.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help